# How to detect mousemove event on after button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a div. I click on the div and move the cursor without releasing the mouse button. In this case mousemove event not working. How to detect the change in position of cursor.....

My sample code is below

```
$scope.volhandlerclick=function($event)
    {
        $scope.volhandclick=true;
        oldPos=angular.element($event.target).prop('offsetLeft');
        angular.element($event.target).bind("mousemove",function(obj)
        {

            console.log(obj.pageX)

        })      

    };
```

Comment: Try to use the `mouseup` event !!

Answer (score 0):

The `click` event only fires after you release the mouse button. You'll need to use `ng-mousedown` instead of `ng-click`.

Answer (score 0):

well you can always do it with ngClick and ngMouseMove... like this

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6ayozof/1/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="rectangle" ng-mousemove="mouseMove()" ng-click="click()">{{message}}</div>
    {{count}}
</div>
```

```
 angular.module('myApp', ['ngTouch'])
    .controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
       $scope.message = "Mouse click and move!";
        $scope.count = 0;
        $scope.click = function() {
            $scope.isClicked = true;
        }; 
        $scope.mouseMove = function(){
            if($scope.isClicked){
        $scope.count++;
            }
        };        
}]);
```

so the fist event is triggered by the click and then you handle everything via mouse move... if you want the offset and what not just pass the $event to the function.

or something like that